# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} kX^2_n=kX^2$ if $\lim_{n\to \infty} X_n=X$.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having a hard time figuring out where to start with this question: show that $\lim_{n→∞} kX^2_n=kX^2$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n=X$.

Can I use the multiplication property of limits and make it $k(X_n)(X_n)$?

Comment: So far, I only have this: we want to show that k|XnXn -X^2| <epsilon |XnXn -X^2| = |(Xn-X)(Xn+X)| I'm not sure what to do after this

Comment: Hint: $|X_n - X|$ can be made small, and $|X_n+X|$ is uniformly bounded (why?). Now choose $n$ appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it follows from basic properties of sequences (of real numbers, assuming that is the situation).  If you are asking how to prove that property, you should show your attempts and where you are stuck (or just consult a standard text that includes it).

Comment: So far, I only have this: we want to show that k|Xn*Xn -X^2| <epsilon
|Xn*Xn -X^2| = |(Xn-X)(Xn+X)|

I'm not sure what to do after this

Comment: It does take a little "trickery" - this video not only shows it but explains it well (and I am being lazy but this seemed reasonable instead of writing it all out).  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zvy860EOlVk

Comment: Product of convergent limits equal the limit of the sequence defined by pointwise product $a_1b_1+a_2b_2+\cdots$.